# Type 'DateTime' is not a subtype of type 'TZDateTime?' in Flutter Project

Tags: flutter, dart

in Terminal error is showing Reading a NULL string not supported here.

```
 DateTime _combineDateWithTime(DateTime date, TimeOfDay time) {
    if (date == null && time == null) {
      return null;
    }
    final dateWithoutTime =
        DateTime.parse(DateFormat("y-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(date));
    return dateWithoutTime
        .add(Duration(hours: time.hour, minutes: time.minute));

  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Proposed solution:

```
DateTime? _setTimeOfDate(DateTime? date, TimeOfDay? time) {
  if (date == null || time == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day, time.hour, time.minute);
}
```

Have fun.

#### Explanation

First of all, if you're working with null safety, you should allow the return type to be null:

```
DateTime? _combineDateWithTime(DateTime date, TimeOfDay time) { ... }
```

(mind the `?` in the return type). In that case, you won't be needing the null checks in the beginning.

If you allow null as parameters, I'd suggest to check for null with an `||` instead of a `&&`.

```
DateTime? _combineDateWithTime(DateTime? date, TimeOfDay? time) {
  if (date == null || time == null) {
    return null;
  }
  ...
}
```

IMHO, without judgement, formatting and parsing the date is a bit strange. I assume the combineDateWithTime function should actually set the date to a specific time, right? (Side note, i'd rename the method to `setTimeOfDate` or similar, to make the naming more specific.)

Please correct me if I'm wrong with my interpretation of what the method should do, but if i assume correctly, you could get the result by using the proposed method above.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.parse expects a string to be present in a format called "TZDateTime" and the output of Dateformat is not in that format, refer this for valid formats: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

Btw, I don't understand why you are converting DateTime to DateFormat and back to DateTime again?

Answer (score 1):

You can use timezone package from pub.dev just you need to initialize it in initstate method and import timezone.dart as tz and use it.